# symfony 1.4 clear cache

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I want to add a directory in /cache. i.e. /cache/custom and if I run command:

```
./symfony clear:cache
```

All files in custom directory gets deleted. I don't want these files deleted even if I run ./symfony cc. Any solution?

Comment: Why don't you write your `custom` folder elsewhere? Like inside `/data`? What did you put inside this folder that can't be re-generated after? A cache folder should improve performance, if you remove stuff inside, it's shouldn't break your app.

Comment: if you want to do this kind of stuff, you can write your own shell script which call ./symfony cache:clear and after rm -rf /cache/custom/*

Answer (score 3):

The cache directory has a different purpose. You should not write your custom files to folders like cache, logs, components, vendor because they are overridden while running some commands or while running the application.